# Cannot access my web application from inside or outside my virtual network

Tags: azure-networking

I have setup a virtual network in azure.   Both have been added to the domain I purchased off godaddy. They are communicating perfectly and have no DNS issues (that I can see). I have setup a security group and added my subnet and added port 443 to the inbound rules. On the webapp server I have added a SSL certificate (bought off godaddy and added the binding).
Now all I need to do is check that the connection is there, from the browsers on the servers I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and on browsers via my laptop (outside my cloud network), I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.  I have spoken to the domain issuer and they see no issues with my domain or certificate.  I must be missing a configuration in my azure virtual network.  Can anyone offer some advice?

This address should display my applications icon

https://support-spi.com/images/appicon.png

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED reads like a firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: You're right it does,  however no firewalls are setup on my servers.  I have confirmed that my azure network security group has inbound rules allowing port 443 to used.   I'm perplexed,  I feel like its DNS related but I cant figure what,  my servers are all setup correctly...I might be missing something extra that azure requires?...